# How do I get the offer to purchase the third office?

Tags: game-dev-story

I am playing Game Dev Story on my Galaxy Ace. I am on year 25, I have $200.000K, I have Mr X and King, two of them are 5 level hackers and I have a Hardware Engineer, but I am still on my 2nd office, as the 3rd office offer never appeared. I want to buy someone from the Holywood Agent, I want to developea few best consoles, and then I will start a new game. But I seriously want my own console. How can I buy the 3rd office?

Comment: Did you try just hiring one more person? I think three should be sufficient - but it already sounds like you should have reached Office #3.

Comment: @StampedeXV office#3 has room for 8 people